# How to properly rotate a Matrix with respect to a parent Matrix?

Tags: unity-game-engine, matrix

I am working with Matrix4x4's in Unity and have some local space Matrices under parent Transforms that have their own rotation, scale and position. Whenever a parent Transform is moved, scaled or rotated I need to reflect it also on to the child Matrices.

For translating the position of the child into worldspace relative to the parent, that seems pretty easy:

```
WorldSpaceMatrix = LocalSpaceMatrix * transform.localToWorldMatrix;
```

However I am really struggling with how to reflect a change in parent rotation on to a child Matrix and also update position due to any position offset. The above gets the local rotation of the Matrix itself which is fine. But it doesn't update any change in position. Effectively I need to "RotateAround" the parent, but I don't know how.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this? Asking to make sure that this is in fact the right direction, or there might be a simpler solution to the actual problem you are trying to solve

Comment: I have built a custom culling system that uses only Matrix4x4's and I'm trying my best to avoid using GameObjects at all as it'll impact the performance of the tool.